# Form not recognizing an ajax generated field

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm doing this little dynamic selects and i want their value to go to an other php. The thing is that the form is only recognizing one of them and the other one (ajax loaded) no.
The query is correct and they change values and the ajax is working it's just that when you press the submit button the ajax field it's not sended along everything else.

Could someone help me?
Here is my code:

```
         <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--  Esto es lo que cambia el combo
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#estados').change(function(){
                var id=$('#estados').val();
                $('#ciudad').load('ajax.php?id='+id);
            });    
        });
    </script>
```

and this is the form:

```
         <table align="center" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2" class="table">
   <form name="Buscar" action="Resultados.php" method="get">
   <tr><td>
      <?php 
    $consulta=mysql_query("SELECT id_estado,nom_estado FROM Estados ORDER BY id_estado ASC");
    echo "<select name='estados' id='estados'>";
    while ($fila=mysql_fetch_array($consulta)){
        echo "<option value='".$fila[0]."'>".utf8_encode($fila[1])."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    ?>
   </td><td>
    <div id="ciudad"> <!-- This is where the ajax go when estado changes-->
        <select name="Ciudades">
            <option value="">Seleccione una Ciudad</option>
        </select>
    </div></td><td>
       <input name="Button" value="BUSCAR" type="submit"  class="button"/>
    </form></td></tr>
    </table>
```

And this is the ajax file

```
    <?php
    $conexion=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $db=mysql_select_db("Region01");

    $consulta = mysql_query("SELECT id_ciudad,nom_ciudad FROM Ciudades WHERE id_estado=".$_GET['id']." ORDER BY nom_ciudad ASC");
    echo "<select name='ciudad' id='ciudad'>";
    while ($fila = mysql_fetch_array($consulta)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $fila[0] . "'>" . utf8_encode($fila[1]) . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    ?>
```

Comment: Does the <select> in your ajax.php page has a "name" attribute ?

Comment: Yes. I'll post that too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to move your  tags like this :

```
   <form name="Buscar" action="Resultados.php" method="get">
     <table align="center" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2" class="table">
       <tr>
         <td>
         <?php 
           $consulta=mysql_query("SELECT id_estado,nom_estado FROM Estados ORDER BY id_estado ASC");
           echo "<select name='estados' id='estados'>";
           while ($fila=mysql_fetch_array($consulta)){
             echo "<option value='".$fila[0]."'>".utf8_encode($fila[1])."</option>";
           }
           echo "</select>";
         ?>
         </td>
         <td>
          <div id="ciudad"> <!-- This is where the ajax go when estado changes-->
           <select name="Ciudades">
             <option value="">Seleccione una Ciudad</option>
           </select>
          </div>
         </td>
         <td>
           <input name="Button" value="BUSCAR" type="submit"  class="button"/>

         </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The option tag needs to be between `<select name="WHAT_EVER"> ... </select>`